# Can i extend the life of Session or instance or control GC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, web-config

i have developed a web application C# in Asp.net. it is a kind of intranet app. There are some pages which are used for Crud processes. But every things is ok in local test. Press F5 :
1) GetList() -> OK
2) AddNew() -> Ok 
3) Save() -> Ok

 But multi user (Real world) is angree this error :
**object reference not set to an instance of an object**

BUT every thing is ok in local. User said that "Yes every thing is ok in 2-3 hours but after afternoon. i see error: object reference not set to an instance of an object"

i have 2 scenario

- that problem is GC.Gc can dispose my instance to make above methods!
- Session to timeout

Please think 2 scenario; how to extend the life of instance or session or control GC or any other best opinion? Thanks...

Best Regards...

Comment: It won't be garbage collection, as that only collects objects that can can't get referenced again.

Comment: It might be useful for us to see a few lines before (if related) and the line causing the exception.

Comment: I am pretty sure the GC is not to blame, and I doubt that it is a session timeout. You are probably misusing some session variable, but in order to be sure, please post your code, including your global.asax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definetly not the Garbage collector as it will not collect memory that is referenced.

The only way you will be sure that the reason is "session expired" or not is to:

1. Find where the error is
2. Detect the reason for it

In your case it might be a little difficult to do debugging since the user is experiencing the error most likely on production. So you need some type of logging system. If you like classic logging then you can use [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/). If you like to be notified by email about exceptions etc. you can use [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/).

Answer (score 3):

You have to be able to reproduce the problem, then use breakpoints / tracing to figure out where the error is. It is not necessarily related to session timeout, but it could be, if your user has not been using the app for 15 minutes or more.

The Garbage Collector does not collect anything that is still in scope, so that cannot be the problem.

So, make sure you can reproduce the problem, you'll probably have it fixed quickly (and if not, report back your findings here!)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `Session` timeout from `web.config`:

```
<sessionState timeout="30"></sessionState>
```

where `timeout` is in minutes. Learn more about configuring the `sessionState` element [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: What will happen after that (timeout="30") ? Session create same problem.is it?

Comment: I must point out that he mentions 2-3 hours; while the default session timeout is 20 mins; wouldnt it be better to add some kind of persistence so that when the user session times out the session state can be recovered?

Comment: If there is no web request for the timeout period, the Session object will be discarded, and the ASP server will try to generate a new Session and all your values from the previous Session will be lost.

Comment: No, the whole Session object expires, you can't increase timeout based on an item from the Session. If you need some information specific to a user, you could also keep it in a cookie.

Comment: please look below : http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/07/aspnet-session-timeouts.html    The short answer to this is that you have a session time when the following conditions are met:

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't set a timeout for your web application, it will fall back to the default of 20 minutes.  If the user has left the screen idle for more than the default time, the session will time out and you will probably get the error you user is experiencing (the infamous yellow screen of death).

You can extend the session state in the web.config, see the following link:

[Setting the session timeout property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx)

@misha has given an example of how to do this.

I would also try what @Roy suggested and try and reproduce the error in the dev environment.

Comment: http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2008/07/aspnet-session-timeouts.html.  The short answer to this is that you have a session time when the following conditions are met: Can i?

Comment: You can extend the session timeout, but not in code as @misha has pointed out above.  You can either use Cookies or set the Timeout property in the Web.Config.  But to make sure it is a session timeout, you need to debug the web app as others have suggested e.g. using log4net or Elmah.

Answer (score 0):

It can be session timeout. I advice to add some logging into Global.asax Session_End event to see when it happens (if at all). This could help you with this error. Putting logging into many places is generally helping to debug difficult or intermittent problems. If you want to go serious about logging check log4net (free) library. Quite powerful.